# If I make a database on Realm, will it be accessible to my user without internet access?

Tags: ios, realm

I'm trying to build my first Swift app and I think Realm may be a good option for my database. This might be a totally stupid question, but will my users be able to access the data on my database without an internet connection? I'm fairly certain that the answer is yes, but I just want to make sure.

*As a side note, I want the data to be stored on the users phone (not a server or anything like that)*

Thanks for the help

Comment: I know nothing about Realm but the tag description says it is a replacement for SQLite and Core Data. Since both of those are local databases, I would have to assume this means Realm is a local database. So no Internet is required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep! Realm is a completely offline, local database solution. There's no online component, but if you do decide to, you can sync data from Realm online using third party cloud services like Parse (Or just literally copying the database file to Dropbox).

By default, all data saved with Realm is stored in a file called 'default.realm' in the Documents directory of your app, but you can easily explicitly set where you want the data to be saved.

Comment: Thank you so much! Realm looks a lot easier to use than SQLite and Core Data. So glad I'll be able to use it. :)

Comment: My pleasure! Absolutely! I moved from Core Data to Realm in one of my own apps, so I can personally recommend it over Core Data. :) Please don't forget to mark this answer as accepted in order to officially close it off! :)